# Kdb upsert with conditional syntax?

Tags: kdb

Is there a way I can upsert in kdb where the following occurs:

1. If key is not present, insert values
2. If key is present, check if current value is greater
   A) If so, perform no action
   B) If not, update values

Something like:

```
job upsert ([title: job1] time: enlist 1 where time > 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using a keyed table, and you want to change values only if they're greater and add in new keys and values, you can try avoiding upsert entirely:

```
t:([job:`a`b`c] val: 4 4 4)    /current table
nt:([job:`a`c`d]val: 6 1 5)    /new values to check

t|nt
job| val
---| ---
a  | 6
b  | 4
c  | 4
d  | 5
```

This will automatically add keys that aren't there, and update the current value to the new value if the new value is larger.

Comment: Premise in the first sentence of this answer is wrong. OP wants new keys inserted.

Answer (score 2):

please find a solution and explanation below. I'll edit if I come up with a better way - thanks. *also I hope I interpreted the question correctly.

```
q)t1
name   | age height
-------| ----------
michael| 26  173
john   | 57  156
sam    | 23  134
jimmy  | 83  183
conor  | 32  145
jim    | 64  167
q)t2
name age height
---------------
john 98  220
mary 24  230
jim  50  240
q)t1 upsert t2 where{$[all null n:x[y`name];1b;y[`age]>n[`age]]}[t1;]each t2
name   | age height
-------| ----------
michael| 26  173
john   | 98  220
sam    | 23  134
jimmy  | 83  183
conor  | 32  145
jim    | 64  167
mary   | 24  230
q)
```

Explanation;
The function takes 2 args, `x` = the keyed table `t1` and `y` = each record from `t2`(as a dictionary). First we extract the `name` value from the `t2` record(`` y`name ``) and try to index into the source keyed table with that value and store the result in the local variable `n`. If the name exists, the corresponding record(`n`, as a dictionary)will be returned from `y`(and `all null n` will be false) otherwise an empty record will be returned(and `all null n` will be true). If we cannot find an instance of the `` t2[`name] `` in t1 then we just return `1b` from the function. Otherwise, then we want to compare the ages between the two records (`` n[`age] `` <-- age referenced in `t1` for the matching name & `` y[`age] `` <-- age of this particular record of `t2`) - if the age for this matching record in `t2` (`` y[`age] ``) is greater than the matching value from `t1` then we return `1b` otherwise we return `0b`.

The result of this function is a list of booleans, one for each record in `t2`. 1b is returned under 2 scenarios - either; 
(1) This particular name from `t2` has no match in `t1`. (2) This name from `t2` does have a match in `t1` and the age is greater than the corresponding age in `t1`. 0b is returned when the age referenced in `t2` is less than the corresponding age from `t1`.

In our example the result of the function is `110b` and after we apply `where` to this, the result is the indexes where the list value is true i.e. `where 110b` --> `0 1`. We use this list to index into `t2` which returns the first 2 records from `t2`(these are either new records or records where the age is greater than what is referenced in `t1`), then we simply upsert this into `t1`.

I hope this helps and hope some better solutions come along.

Comment: Post an example of your tables. My t1 is keyed on name and t2 is an unkeyed table.

Comment: Mea culpa: my `t2` was keyed.

Answer (score 2):

For a table, a key, and a value: upsert the tuple if the key is new or the value exceeds the existing value.

```
q)t:([job:`a`b`c] val: 4 4 4)    /current table
q)t[`a]|:6                       /old key, higher value
q)t
job| val
---| ---
a  | 6
b  | 4
c  | 4
q)t[`c]|:1                       /old key, lower value
q)t
job| val
---| ---
a  | 6
b  | 4
c  | 4
q)t[`d]|:5                       /new key
q)t
job| val
---| ---
a  | 6
b  | 4
c  | 4
d  | 5
```

**Remarks**

A keyed table with a single data column could perhaps be a dictionary.

[Amending through an operator](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/syntax/#naming-and-assignment) works also with a new key.

Upserting a table (or dictionary) of new records is more efficient *and simpler* than updating a single tuple.

```
q)nt:([job:`a`c`d]val: 6 1 5)    /new values to check
q)t|nt                           /maximum of two tables
job| val
---| ---
a  | 6
b  | 4
c  | 4
d  | 5
```

or just

```
q)t[([]job:`a`c`d)]|:([]val:6 1 5)
```

Simple-looking primitives such as [*maximum* (`|`)](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/arith-integer/#or-maximum) repay careful study.

Comment: This appears to be a very close copy of a prior answer by @Ryan McCarron

Comment: This is a much more thorough explanation than mine - OP would maybe learn more from reading this